# uiswitch in uitableview persistence when close and reopen the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I would like to ask about uiswitch in uitableview custom cell.

if I have array that keeps state of each uiswitch in the table and update it on Change Value Event.However this changes are not persistence each time i open the app it reset to it's initial state. My question is how to make the changes persistent on my app whenever i close it and reopen it again ?

Here is my change value code:

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *x=[mainTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSMutableArray *repl = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    if (sender.on)
    {
        repl= [SwitchArray objectAtIndex:x.section] ;
        [repl replaceObjectAtIndex:x.row withObject:@"ON"];


    }
    else
    {
        //call the first array by section
        repl= [SwitchArray objectAtIndex:x.section] ;
        [repl replaceObjectAtIndex:x.row withObject:@"OFF"];

   }
}
```

Here is the initial values of the array in viewDidLoad:

```
for(int j=0 ; j < 30 ; j++)
                 [switchArray addObject:@"ON"];
```

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your collaboration This will make me happy

Comment: How are you persisting the array? NSUserDefaults, Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to persist the array between uses of the app is to write out the array to a pList.

In order to do so you'll need a place to store the file, take the following example:

```
- (NSURL *)switchArrayFilePath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SwitchArray.plist"]];

    return filePath;
}
```

Then in order to load up your array, you can read the pList back in in `viewDidLoad:` for instance:

```
self.switchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self switchArrayFilePath]];
```

Then in order to write out the data, you could so something like this in `viewWillDisappear:`

```
[self.switchArray writeToURL:[self switchArrayFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Other ways to persist this type of data on iOS would be use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or use Core Data but that would be complex for something simple like this.

Hope that helps!